# HTML put an icon in front of webpage

Tags: html, css, icons, sidebar

Until now I got a webpage with a navigation bar, which is responsible to screensize, all is fine until this point. 
But now it becomes a bit strange for me, I want to add a search icon (loupe) in the bottom left hand corner. My idea was to use the "aside" element (or "aside" section?) which is supported in html5, but if I put my icon in this aside element it is not visible. I hope you can help me. here some html code:

```
HERE IS SOME OTHER CODE WHICH WORKS PERFECT
.
.
.

<!-- Search Icon beginn -->
<aside>
  <div class="searchicon">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/Searchicon.png" alt="Search" height="30px" width="30px"></a>

  </div>
</aside>

<!-- Search Icon end -->

</body>
```

My plan is that the search icon is always on the left of the webpage (kind of a sidebar), I don't want to cover up the text which is at the site later on.

Thanks to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the z-index in css which will basically move an HTML element forward/backward :

```
.searchicon {
    z-index: 2;
}

/*
Set the value to negative if you want the element to move backwards.
*/
```

Comment: nice, didn't know that this works, but sure why this doesn't come in my mind... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The positioning of HTML elements is controlled in your CSS. In your case this is the `searchicon` class. You haven't provided the CSS but it might look something like this:

```
.searchicon {
    position: fixed;
    left: 150px;
    bottom: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

As a note, the [aside element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside) may not be the *"most semantic"* option based on what you've described. The HTML5 aside is intended to contain content that doesn't directly relate to the pages primary content. For example a sidebar containing related articles.

Comment: ah ok, good to know. thanks to you aswell. 
My css looks like yours, but I used "position: absolute;" instead of fixed. both works for my case. whats the difference?

Comment: Position `fixed` will lock to the screen as you scroll down, position `absolute` will stay in the one place. Some examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).